# Allow setting custom timers/alarms on questions

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

I sometimes get an answer to a question that has me thinking:

"This will work.  But I don't like it very much.  I am going to move on to something else and come back to this later and see if I have gotten a better answer."

(This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802123/is-there-a-way-to-do-and-in-net-sql-azman-instead-of-or) is my current example.)

Unfortunately, "later" does not always happen.  I forget about the question and the user who posted a workable solution (if not as good as I wanted) did not get the credit deserved.

I would like to request the ability to put a timer on a question.  Something like "In 5 days have this pop up in my StackExchange inbox."

That way I will not forget a question that has a correct answer.

This also saves me the work of going back through all my questions that do not have an answer "marked" looking for questions that fit this category.

Comment: How about a reminder in your Outlook/mobile phone?

Comment: IMO this shouldn't be built into the system unless it's something like the "have you considered accepting an answer for this?" message that shows up in your profile--and we already have that.

Comment: I don't think this is a dumb suggestion. Why should I have to set a reminder in my personal calendar to be reminded of looking at some SO question? Something like this could be easily achieved through a better favourites system ( = one that allows for some amount of organizing into folders/tags), which has been said to be in the works for quite some time already. Any news on that, SE team?

Comment: @Pekka Who said it was dumb? The community seems to be disagreeing with the suggestion, but no one said, or even implied that it's dumb.

Answer (score 4):

In a way, this is kind of already in place. If you haven't accepted an answer for a question (that has one) it pops up in your profile and reminds you to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Along the same vein, I would like to see a 'General Cleanup' notification, that (when clicked on) takes you to a page, with a list of "unmarked-answer" questions (that have at least one answer, possibly with an upvote) that says something along the lines of:

> Hey, you have questions with upvoted answers, if the answers are helpful, please consider marking them as the answer to the question.
>
> Alternatively, if you came across a solution to your problem that hasn't been submitted by another user, you can answer your own question
>
> {List of Questions}

I would think that if this popped into your global inbox or notification tray once a month, you'd be more inclined to re-visit the question(s), accept an answer or write your own.

What do you think?